# Hibernate can't create table

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I just started to user hibernate and i allways get this Error:

ERROR:   HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table User (id bigint not null auto_increment, mail varchar(255), passwort varchar(255), primary key (id))
ERROR:   Got error -1 from storage engine

This is my mapped class:

```
package Entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User 
{
private long id;
private String mail;
private String passwort;

@Id
@GeneratedValue  
@Column(name="id")
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="mail")
public String getMail() {
    return mail;
}

public void setMail(String mail) {
    this.mail = mail;
}

@Column(name="passwort")
public String getPasswort() {
    return passwort;
}

public void setPasswort(String passwort) {
    this.passwort = passwort;
}


}
```

Comment: Could you post your hibernate configuration here.

Comment: This looks like very regular issue http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/01/hibernate-hbm2ddl-wont-create-schema.html

Answer (score 2):

It is because "User" is a reserved keyword. You should change your table name.

The annotation below is the solution for this issue.

@Table(name = "users")

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
      <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: do you know if the schema is already created when you tried this? hbm2ddl.auto should be create I belive if you are running the hibernate for the first time on this DB.

Comment: No I think it isn't created

Comment: http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/01/hibernate-hbm2ddl-wont-create-schema.html check this link

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I had same issue. Then I just change the name for table with @Table(name="Users") annotation and it started to work.

So try changing this
    @Entity
public class User 
{
}

to This:

@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class User 
{
}

Answer (score -2):

#### Wrong

```
@Entity /* It will map POJO class with DB Table i,e. Hibernate mapping */
@Table() /* Create Table in DB */
public class User {
}
```

#### Right

```
@Entity /* It will map POJO class with DB Table i,e. Hibernate mapping */
@Table(name="F2CUSER") /* Create Table in DB */
public class User {
}
```

Here I have use `@Table(name="F2CUSER")` and it works for me