# Failed to load ApplicationContext during unit test

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, spring-boot, hsqldb

I am quite new to java EE spring boot and thought I would start a small project to get to grips with things,  I am currently getting an error as stated above `failed to load ApplicationContext` and I am not sure why I am getting this.

Here is my test class:

```
package com.picto.controllers;
//import com.picto.BaseTest;

import com.picto.PictoApplication;
import com.picto.models.User;
import com.picto.repository.UserRepository;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.put;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup;


/**
 * Created by Johnathon on 02/10/2016.
 */

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private final MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new UserController()).build();

    @Test
    public void Get() throws Exception {

        this.entityManager.persist(new User("hi", "hi", "1234567"));

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/user"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

and here is the stack trace:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:47)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [create table users (id bigint not null auto_increment, fullname varchar(255) not null, password varchar(255) not null, username varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:420)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.createTable(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: AUTO_INCREMENT
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: AUTO_INCREMENT
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.readTableContentsSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.compileCreateTableBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.compileCreateTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileCreate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 62 more
```

Here is my User model which I have just changed, before I was using GenerationType.AUTO and have no switched to IDENTITY, however I am still getting the same error

```
package com.picto.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 * Created by Johnathon on 06/10/2016.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {


    //Auto generated id which is unique to each user
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotNull(message = "error.username.null")
    private String username;

    @NotNull(message = "error.fullname.null")
    private String fullname;

    @NotNull(message = "error.password.null")
    @Size(min = 6, message = "error.password.length")
    private String password;

    public User(){}

    public User(long id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User(String username, String fullname, String password){
        this.username = username;
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public long Id(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String Username(){
        return this.username;
    }

    public void EditUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String Fullname(){
        return this.fullname;
    }

    public void EditFullname(String fullname){
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public void EditPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

and here is my application.properties file where I setup the database connection properties:

```
    # ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database "pictodb"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pictodb?useSSL=false

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Can you add the database you are using?

Comment: I am trying to use mysql in this instance, however for unit tests I want to be able to utilise an in memory database instead of having to use external dbs

Comment: What about the new stacktrace? Can you post it? It should have no AUTO_INCREMENT problem anymore, I think it's something else...

Comment: @Igor I have already posted the newest stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

You should look a the first and the last reason in the exception stack trace. The first one says that it can't build the context for spring because some hibernate bean fail to initialize. The last one says this:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Which means that you have an error in hsql:

```
create table users (id bigint not null auto_increment, fullname varchar(255), password varchar(255), username varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

I've found this question that might be useful to you: [Hibernate can't create table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639751/hibernate-cant-create-table)

Comment: Hi, Igor I have modified my User model to use GenerationType.IDENTITY instead of AUTO, however I am still getting the same error.  I have posted my model if that is of any help

Comment: Well, you shouldn't get *exactly* the same error, since you removed AUTO_INCREMENT. Can you update the stacktrace with the one you are getting now, please?

Answer (score 1):

In HSQLDB, `auto-increment` keyword doesn't exit.
To address that need, `IDENTITY` keyword should be used.

Examples from official documentation :

```
 /* this table has no primary key */
 CREATE TABLE vals (id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, data VARBINARY(2000))

 /* in this table id becomes primary key because the old syntax is used - avoid this syntax */
 CREATE TABLE vals (id INTEGER IDENTITY, data VARBINARY(2000))

 /* use the standard syntax and explicity declare a primary key identity column */
 CREATE TABLE vals (id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, data VARBINARY(2000))
```

Official documentation :

> Identity Auto-Increment Columns
>
> Each table can contain a single auto-increment column, known as the
>   IDENTITY column. An IDENTITY column is a SMALLINT, INTEGER, BIGINT,
>   DECIMAL or NUMERIC column with its value generated by a sequence
>   generator.
>
> In HyperSQL 2.0, an IDENTITY column is not by default treated as the
>   primary key for the table (as a result, multi-column primary keys are
>   possible with an IDENTITY column present). Use the SQL standard syntax
>   for declaration of the IDENTITY column.